# Yocto SDK Missing Files

Tags: c++, boost, yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto project that requires boost. I have added boost and I can confirm that the boost libraries are placed into my SDK.

To create my SDK I run the command

```
DISTRO=fsl-imx-fb MACHINE=imx6ull14x14evk bitbake mainapplication-dev -c populate_sdk
```

This builds my image without my main application installed, the main application is run using eclipse.

In my image bitbake file I have the lines

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " boost"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " boost-staticdev"
```

I was looking around and found that the second line above should solve my issue. It does not. My application is complaining that:

```
fatal error: boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp: No such file or directory
```

And it is correct, this file does not exist in my Yocto SDK. I have searched in all files/folders in `/opt/fsl-imx-fb/5.10-hardknott/sysroots`.

What do I need to add to my bitbake file to get ALL of the required boost header files?

Edit: I changed `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " boost-staticdev"` to `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-boost-dev"`. This changes nothing.

Edit: I have attempted to use `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " boost-staticdev"`, this just gives me an error `Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'boost-staticdev'.`

Edit: Looking into my main application `recipe-sysroot` folder I see that `managed_shared_memory.hpp` exists. This is in the sysroot of my recipe but not in my SDK and I am unsure as to why.

Edit: I am building my dev version of the application. The bitbake file I was adding the `DEPENDS += " boost"` was not included in the build. I have since moved this to another recipe. The issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in my testing. I would export the new SDK but never installed it. The steps to solve this issue for me are

1. Add `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " boost-staticdev"` to my recipe bitbake file
2. Run `DISTRO=fsl-imx-fb MACHINE=imx6ull14x14evk bitbake mainapplication-dev -c populate_sdk`
3. `cd tmp/deploy/sdk/`
4. `./fsl-imx-fb-glibc-x86_64-mainapplication-dev-cortexa7t2hf-neon-imx6ull14x14evk-toolchain-5.10-hardknott.sh`
5. `source /opt/fsl-imx-fb/5.10-hardknott/environment-setup-cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`
6. Run eclipse and build